# How can I change the directory in wich pam_mkhomedir creates the user's home directories?

Tags: linux, pam, home-directory

I am using pam_mkhomedir to automatically create user's home directories when they first log in.

However, the home directories are created inside the `/home` directory, while i need them to be created inside another one (`/users/home`).

How can this be achieved ?

Extra info:

- Editing `/etc/default/useradd` does not help.
- The only options that can be passed to pam_mkhomedir are the path to an alternative "skel" directory and a permissions mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The homedir *should* be created in the path for the homedir specified in the users entry in `/etc/passwd` (or other similar account sources like an LDAP directory). Did you try to change that?

This entry is the authoritative declaration of where the users homedir is (and should be created).

Comment: Users are authenticated from a LDAP server, but your answer made me realize that their home directory path is indeed wrong (/etc/home) in the LDAP directory. Sorry about that - changing to the right value did fix the "problem".

Answer (score 0):

What if someone is using realmd and autofs? sssd/winbind injects active directory users into the passwd (getent passwd $USER) along with their home folder which is sometimes retrieved from the RID/AD backend. That means some AD users I want oddjob to create /home/$DOMAIN/$USER home folders for,(SSH users specifically) but other AD user's belonging to ftponly/sftponly AD group have a home folder set in /sftponly folder. This sftponly folder cannot have oddjob messing around in there because it uses autofs and it totally breaks autofs wildcards. Why does oddjobd-mkhomedir.conf assume I want all folders to be affected? Surely someone has requested an include_dir= or exclude_dir= parameter before me?